# AWS DynamoDB Transaction issues (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, transactions, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am trying to update 2 tables transactionally. first table is called CUSTOMER_TABLE, second is called CUSTOMER_JOB_TABLE.

for the first table, I create a new row if it doesnt exist. if it does exist i add to the currentProcessedCount column the value from this specific process. for the second table, i always create a new row. the 2 updates need to be transactional. i get the following error and I cant figure out what the reason is. Can someone help?

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (TransactionCanceledException) when calling the TransactWriteItems operation: Transaction cancelled, please refer cancellation reasons for specific reasons [ValidationError, None]",
  "errorType": "TransactionCanceledException",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \\"/var/task/app.py\\", line 149, in lambda_handler\\n    c_table_response = update_customer_table(customer_id, customer_monthly_limit, number_of_rows,\\n",
    "  File \\"/var/task/app.py\\", line 226, in update_customer_table\\n    response = dynamodb_client.transact_write_items(\\n",
    "  File \\"/opt/python/botocore/client.py\\", line 316, in _api_call\\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\\n",
    "  File \\"/opt/python/botocore/client.py\\", line 635, in _make_api_call\\n    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)\\n"
  ]
}
```

below is my method for the call

```
import boto3
dynamodb_client = boto3.client('dynamodb')
# grab static env variable
CUSTOMER_ID = os.environ['CUSTOMER_ID']
BUCKET_NAME = os.environ['BUCKET_NAME']
CUSTOMER_TABLE_NAME = os.environ['CUSTOMER_TABLE_NAME']
CUSTOMER_JOB_TABLE_NAME = os.environ['CUSTOMER_JOB_TABLE_NAME']

def update_customer_table(customer_id, customer_monthly_limit, number_of_rows, year_month, uuid, date_time, batch_no):
    response = dynamodb_client.transact_write_items(
        TransactItems=[
            {
                'Update': {
                    'TableName': CUSTOMER_TABLE_NAME,
                    'Key': {
                        'PK': {'S': customer_id},
                        'SK': {'N': str(year_month)},
                    },
                    'ExpressionAttributeNames': {
                        '#ml': "MonthlyLimit",
                        '#cpc': "currentProcessedCount"
                    },
                    'ExpressionAttributeValues': {
                        ':ml': {'N': str(customer_monthly_limit)},
                        ':cpc': {'N': str(number_of_rows)}
                    },
                    'UpdateExpression': "SET #ml = :ml ADD #cpc :cpc"
                }
            },
            {
                'Put': {
                    'TableName': CUSTOMER_JOB_TABLE_NAME,
                    'Item': {
                        'PK': {'S': f'{customer_id}_{uuid}'},
                        'SK': {'N': str(year_month)},
                        'CustomerId': {'S': customer_id},
                        'UUID': {'S': uuid},
                        'StartDateTime': {'N': date_time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M')},
                        'NumberOfSplitFiles': {'N': str(batch_no - 1)},
                        'TotalRowCount': {'N': str(number_of_rows)}

                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    )

    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem, not sure if it's the only one.

```
               'ExpressionAttributeValues': {
                    ':ml': {'N': str(customer_monthly_limit)},
                    ':cpc': {'N': str(number_of_rows)}
                },
                'UpdateExpression': "SET #ml = :mlv ADD #cpc :cpc"
```

`:mlv` doesn't match `:ml`

Comment: Spotted that, it still has the same issue after i fixed that